# Adding transition together with multiple overlay images using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg for image overlay.

I have multiple images, which I wanted to overlay. My below code workd great for this.

```
ffmpeg -i D:/Test.mp4 
-i D:\Images\test.jpg 
-i D:\Images\test2.jpg 

-filter_complex  "[0][1]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,1237.216831,1837.216831)'[v1];
[v1][2]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,2237.216831,2469.729935)'[v2]"

 -map "[v2]" -map 0:a
 D:\ffmpeg_output\output.mp4
```

Now, I wanted to bring different effects at the time of image overlay. I learnt give effects using code

```
xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=408.84
```

How do I apply transitions in my overlay image code together?

Please guide.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. xfade is used to transition 2 inputs: one right after the other. Like a crossfade. But your 2 overlays have a gap in the timestamps between them. How should a transition occur between 2 videos that are temporally non-contiguous?

Comment: Got your point and understood on xfade side. Basically, On my video, I wanted that entire Video should be overlayed for certain time and that is happening great. But the image which comes, I wanted that image should have some effects while coming. Image should not come all of sudden. So, I was trying to bring and put all different type of effects which we have in xfade. How can I bring effects for images? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give alpha channel to each image with the format filter, then add the [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i image1.jpg -loop 1 -i image2.jpg 
-filter_complex "[1]format=yuva444p,fade=t=in:st=2237.216831:d=1:alpha=1[img1];[2]format=yuva444p,fade=t=in:st=2237.216831:d=1:alpha=1[img2];[0][img1]overlay=x=0:y=0:format=auto:enable='between(t,2237.216831,2469.729935)':shortest=1[bg];[bg][img2]overlay=x=0:y=0:format=auto:enable='between(t,2237.216831,2469.729935)':shortest=1,format=yuv420p"
-c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Many Many thanks for your great support. Salute to you.